Replication broken - postgres - AWS RDS Blue/Green - Refresh Materialized View
I found out the following about AWS Blue/Green (Blue Postgres 14, Green Postgres 16):

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY always degrades GREEN.
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW (without CONCURRENTLY) degrades GREEN, only if done before GREEN is fully set up (e.g. before upgrade of GREEN from postgres 14 to postgres 16 is done). It does not degrade GREEN, if done after GREEN is fully set up.

In my scenario it takes about 4 hours until GREEN is fully set up. And we rely on materialized view refreshes every minute for our software to function properly.
So that there is no way to refresh materialized views for 4 hours during the upgrade is a real show stopper for the upgrade for us.
I could replace the materialized views with normal tables and delete all rows from these tables every minute while inserting the results of the materialized-view-select. Basically writing the REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW (CONCURRENTLY) functionality myself...
AWS Support says that the behaviour of their Blue/Green logic is fine and they won't change it...
But is there a better way? This seems to be a limitation/defect in AWS Blue/Green logic. This does not seem to be a limitation of postgres logical replication?

From the manual: Replication is only supported by tables, including partitioned tables. Attempts to replicate other types of relations, such as views, materialized views, or foreign tables, will result in an error. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-restrictions.html

@FrankHeikens TY for the insight. But it is still not clear to me why AWS blue/green behaves the way it does. They DO support upgrading a DB that has materialized views via blue/green and they CAN be refreshed on blue while the blue/green is in place. Just not BEFORE green is 'fully set up'.

@Peter - Did you ever figure out a resolution to this? We are unable to reproduce blue-green failures in our Staging environment with materialized view refreshes, but experience them in our Production environment where logging implies the REFRESH was causing the failure. We never experienced this with our traditional PGLogical harnesses and are debating abandoning the RDS Blue-Green solution.

@Brent Does your staging env have higher source or target pg versions that your production environment maybe? Maybe AWS has improved this from 16.3 onwards: "The blue/green deployment switchover won’t be blocked by the REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW statement." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-versions.html#postgresql-versions-version163).

@Brent My resolution was to prevent all mview refreshes during the blue/green phase by rewriting all places where we use mviews to use normal tables instead, for which I wrote an automatic-table-refresh feature. Basically I implemented mview functionality without mviews... I am a bit hopeful that when I use blue/green the next time (to go from 16.x to 17.x) that this is not needed anymore and I can just leave the mviews, but I will test that thoroughly beforehand.

@Peter - So, we have actually reproduced this with CONCURRENTLY based MV refreshes between PG 16.1 -> 17.2, whereas non-CONCURRENTLY MV refreshes do not seem to trigger the failure. Some of our views have to be refreshed concurrently unfortunately, to prevent locking issues, so we're left reverting to our classic PGLogical harness, which does not fail on the internally generated "CREATE TEMP TABLE" and "DROP TABLE" statements CONCURRENTLY generates. FWIW - We believe that in our testing of PG17 -> PG17 Blue Green, we did not see this issue as a failing DDL detection, just 16->17.

@Brent They have "Unblocked ALTER TEMP TABLE and DROP TEMP TABLE in Blue/Green replication" in their 17.1 release notes. Which would explain what you are seeing.

@Peter - That is encouraging and must also apply to CREATE TEMP TABLE statements, potentially rendering this issue irrelevant, going forward. Wish they had just said concurrent refreshes were unsupported in < 16x, though!
